# Rails, form that can work with different controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, model-view-controller, form-for

I want to make erb template of searchbar that will call `search` method of its controller. Different controllers got same method, but will have different logic. Is it possible to make form that will work with every controller just by rendering it on their views?

--- UPDATE ---
I have found that kind of solution:

```
<%= form_tag "#{controller_name}/search", method: 'get' do  %>
    <div class="input-group">
        <%= text_field_tag :sub_string, '', class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Search..." %>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <%= submit_tag 'Search', class: %w(btn btn-primary) %>
    </span>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

However when I hit the submit button, it goes to `search` action of my current controller and it thows an error:
`Couldn't find Basis with 'id'=search`

it tries to call `set_basis` private method, even if it is not called by `before_action`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set search form's controllers name with params[:controller].

Use [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) to see how to pass controller and action for a form_tag or form_for.

Comment: The only method I see, is to create helper method that will construct me form by taking some arguments(for setting up) and gives me back html_safe string.

Comment: Dude, its a little bad approach. You can place general forms/html in application.html.erb(layout) file. Your form 'll be common in all your application views.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can 
create the template/partial under views/shared folder
then in controller do something like

```
def search 
  render :partial => "shared/search"
end
```

Ok Then add this 
in your partial so you can dynamically change your controller for the form

```
form_tag({controller: controller.controller_name, action: "search_action"}, method: "post", class: "form")
```

Comment: That I intend to do, but how can I make this form make request back to `search` action of `this` controller?